# Complex (deeply nested) request validation in ServiceStack, using Fluent Validation

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I'm coming up short, trying to use Fluent Validation in the ServiceStack DTOs, when the model have properties nested several levels.

Ex.: The model is structured like this
A => B => C => D
                           => E

To validate B without risking a nullref. exception, I need to (successfully) validate A.

To Validate C, A  and B must be not null.

D and E have cross dependencies so to validate E then A, B, C AND D must not be null.

The only way that is seemingly available for this scenario, is wrapping the entire thing in when/dependent blocks, but that quickly becomes unmanageable.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatives of using multiple validators constrained by `When()` blocks is to either use a ["Must" predicate validator](https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators.html#predicate-validator), create a [Custom Validator](https://fluentvalidation.net/custom-validators) or avoid using Fluent Validation for these complex validations and validate them in your Service where you can use full C# to validate them as normal.

Throwing a `ArgumentException(message,paramName)` in your Service using the name of the Request DTO property will populate the Error in the structured `ResponseStatus` Errors collection.